# Database of customers and their PW Vs user account per customer Banking WEB APP

Tags: mysql, sql, ajax, database, database-design

Hi I am getting confused between a “User” of a database and a “Customer” of a business accessing their details from the database.

I am building a web all where a customer can log in and access their bank balance, statement, direct debits etc (banking application). My sql database will have a customer table with their info, account table with balance etc, statement table with date time etc etc etc.

My question is, in a real world thousands of customers can have a bank account. In sql do we create a user per customer with the relevant permissions to access certain data or preset views.

I was under the impression my database only needed one user root (me) and I have a table of customers with PW. I validate the customer against pw field using Javascript on login page, if it matches then ill just have JS/Java methods to connect and execute sql statements against the DB like:
For (customer) select Balance from account where customer no = (provided cust no from login screen by user input).

So in a nutshell does every customer from a possible million need a user account on the db or can we just have back-end methods to retrieve relevant info against a primary key like a customer no or username.

I have thoroughly researched this questions but cant seem to find answers, probably because im finding it difficult to explain my perspective. Could someone please clear it up for me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your application...

You definitely need a layer between the "customer" and the "data".  Customer must never be able to *directly* connect to the database.  They *must* go through the layer.

That layer will involve code and databases.  The database tables will have customer names, addresses, encrypted passwords, etc.  The code will do the validation, etc.

As far as MySQL is concerned, there may be exactly 2 "users":

- `root` for administration, and
- `...` for the single "user" that is the go-between to handle all the 'banking' actions and talk to the rest of the databases.

There should be at least two `DATABASEs`, each with different `TABLEs`:

- The admin db -- users, names, pwds, etc.
- The "money" -- accounts, audit_trail, statements, etc.

The only reason for a `statement` table is to freeze the statement so that if there is a dispute, you at least have a copy of the statement.  Since a statement is completely redundant, it *could* be just a PDF file.

If you have a million "users", some tables will have a million rows; some may have lots more rows.

If you are working with real "money", then you need a *very serious security audit* of everything you are doing.  That is beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: Thank you for this! Just a few things thought; what do you mean by the whole “statement table is completely redundant”? Also, I’m presuming the two users admin would have root privelages and user would have just read/write permissions, but accessed through mid/back-end methods rather than user accessing DB directly? Finally, for a beginners FYP at Uni, can you explain how I can implement audit logging and other security features? Thanks

Comment: @Hgrammer - Presumably everything in `statement` is derived from the other tables.  As for auditing, security, etc, those topics are too big for this forum.